# Cómo puedo hacer para contar números positivos y negativos en un array en php

Tags: php, array

Esto utilice para los negativos pero no sé que poner para los positivos y soy nueva en esto

```
$negativos = preg_grep(/^\-\d*\.?\d+$,$num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de una manera más sencilla utilizando la función array_filter de PHP

```
 $negativos = array_filter( $num, function($valor) {  return $valor<0;  });
 $positivos = array_filter( $num, function($valor) {  return $valor>=0;  });
```

array_filter el primer parametro es el array que deseas filtrar, el segundo es una función, en este caso una función anónima, que debe retornar un true o false para cada valor, los valores que devuelven true, se incluyen en un array nuevo que será el retorno de array_filter.

te dejo la documentación de PHP
[array_filter-php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)